# Forcing function IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Problem: 
Solve the following initial value problem: $$y''+y'+(5/4)y=g(t)$$where 
$$g(t)=\begin{cases}
\sin(t) & 0 \le t\le \pi\\
0& t>\pi
\end{cases}$$ and $ y(0)=0, y'(0)=0$.

So far: I don't have much. I took the LaPlace transform and ended up with the following: $$L\{y\}=\frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{(s^2+1)((s+1/2)^2+1)}$$.
From what I can tell, a partial fraction decomposition of that expression would not bring me closer to an answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your Laplace transform of $g(t)$ is wrong. For $g(t)$, $$g(t) =(1 - h(t-\pi))\sin(t) = \sin(t) + h(t-\pi)\sin(t-\pi)$$
where $h$ is the heaviside step function. So the transform is $$L\{g\}=\frac{1+e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1}.$$

Secondly, partial fractions will allow you to solve this; as
$$L\{y\}=\frac{1+e^{-\pi s}}{(s^2+1)((s+1/2)^2+1)}
=\frac{4(1+e^{-\pi s})}{17}\left[\frac{4s+3}{(s+1/2)^2+1} - \frac{4s-1}{s^2+1}\right]$$
Which will clearly produce solutions in terms of trig functions and the step function which i will leave you to finish.